# Save the field Name field in combobox LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox, name

Hello I was trying to save in a lightning-combobox the field Name from record of an SObject, but it is not working.
My apex class:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable= True)
public static List<String> getNameFiledsRecords(){
    List<SObject> recordsList = new  List<SObject>();
    List<String> namesToReturn = new List<String>();
    recordsList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM SObject];

    for(SObject i: recordsList){
        namesToReturn.add(i.Name);
    }
    return namesToReturn;
}
```

In my js code:

```
@track options = [];
connectedCallback(){
     getNameFiledsRecords().then(result => {
        if(result != null){
            for(let iName in result){
                this.options.push({label: iName, value: iName});
            }
        }
    })
}
```

In my html:

```
<lightning-combobox label="Choose an option" required
        options={options}
        onchange={handleSelection} ></lightning-combobox>
```

The problem is that it returns me numbers:

```
[{"label":"0","value":"0"},{"label":"1","value":"1"},{"label":"2","value":"2"}]
```

Could anybody help me to return the name? Thanks
Can do an example of a code?

Comment: Looks like that `Sobject.Name` is a number.

Comment: @Dameck no, in the console.log I saw what the apex method brought me and it was the names: Asociación Comunidad Energética Toledo,Asociación Comunidad Energética Valencia,AranjuezCity

Comment: @TechGuy can you share the contents of the handleSelection() method?

Comment: Sorry I figure it out. I need to put: this.nombresComunidadesEnergeticas.push({label: result[iName], value: result[iName]});

Comment: I guess this can be easily fixed by using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 0):

My bad I needed to write it correctly:

```
@track options = [];
connectedCallback(){
 getNameFiledsRecords().then(result => {
    if(result != null){
        for(let iName in result){
            this.options.push({label: result[iName], value: result[iName]});
        }
    }
})
}
```

Comment: does it work? because I tried the same code and it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, you almost always want the ID of the record. In other words, your Apex would look like this:

```
 @AuraEnabled public static sObject[] getNameFiledRecords() {
   return [SELECT Name FROM sObject];
 }
```

And then you can translate this information client-side:

```
async connectedCallback() {
  let result = await getNameFiledRecords();
  this.options = result?.map((record)=>({ value: record.Id, label: record.Name })) || [];
}
```

Now, when you check the value, it'll have the unique Id, which you can find the label for if you need it:

```
const selectedLabel = this.options.find((option)=>option.value===event.target.value)?.label;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **for...of** instead of **for...in**

**for...in**: It iterates over object property and in case of list/array it iterates over index. Read more about [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

**for...of**: It iterates over object value and in case of list/array it iterates over value. Read more about [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)